# Output is empty when showing 4 rows of data and remove last row

Tags: javascript, php, html, nodes, server-sent-events

I perform the event stream to stream data from the php script. I want to limit to 4 rows of data. Thus, i input the code to remove if the count is more than or equal to 4 rows. When I run the file, the output is empty but when I checked in the network tab, I could see the script continuously being executed.

Here is my code below..

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
const result = document.getElementById("result");
    if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("randomData.php");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            //Redefine node at each message event
            const node = document.createTextNode(event.data + "\n");
            if ($("#result p").length >= 4) {
                $("#result p:last").remove();
            }
            result.insertBefore("<p>"+node+"</p>", result.firstChild);    
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php code

```
    <?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$countryarr = array("UNITED STATES", "INDIA", "SINGAPORE","MALAYSIA","COLOMBIA","THAILAND","ALGERIA","ENGLAND","CANADA","CHINA", "SAUDI ARABIA");
$length = sizeof($countryarr)-1;
$random = rand(0,$length);
$random1 = rand(0,$length);

$random_srccountry = $countryarr[$random];
$random_dstcountry = $countryarr[$random1];
echo "data: [X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [".$random_srccountry."] TO [".$random_dstcountry."]  \n\n";
flush();
?>
```

What is the cause of the empty output??
Please help me correct the error and also I want to see the output. thank you...

Comment: your code will generate only one line... ever. Please took a moment and read about the right behavior of EventSource and how a php code should look like.

Comment: I have updated my code and the error state

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined
    at EventSource.source.onmessage

Comment: `count()` is a php function to count arrays, you want to use `length` instead like: `if ($("#result p").length >= 4) {...etc` see if that works.

Comment: now there is anohter error which states Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at EventSource.source.onmessage  on line 21

Comment: Just do `console.log(result);` before `const result = document.getElementById("result");` and see what that actually is. Maybe it's not what you expect